# How to query some properties of a list of typenames in a GeoServer WFS

Tags: wfs, filter, getfeature

I want to query selected propertynames from a list of Typenames in a GeoServer service.

I could find an example from OGC WFS 1.1.0 Implementation Specification ( PDF document page 80 Example 10) which is not working for me. Here is the example:

Example 10

Query some properties of a list of feature types. In this case, the attributes WKB_GEOM and TILE_ID are fetched for the INWATERA_1M feature type and all the attributes of feature type BUILTUPA_1M are fetched.

```
http://www.someserver.com/wfs.cgi?
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=1.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
PROPERTY=(INWATERA_1M/WKB_GEOM,INWATERA_1M/TILE_ID)(BUILTUPA_1M/*)&
TYPENAME=INWATERA_1M,BUILTUPA_1M&
```

When I try to implement this I got the following error:

"Requested property: PropertyName1 is not available"   The possible propertyName values are:[PropertyName1, , , , , ]"

It would be  great if someone give me a working example for GeoServer.

Comment: can you provide a link to the spec you mean? There is no WMS 1.1.0 and the WFS 1.1.0 (OGC-04-094) does not have an example on either physical or virtual page 80.

Comment: Here is the link for the pdf : http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.opengeospatial.org%2Ffiles%2F%3Fartifact_id%3D1081%26version%3D1%26format%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=OGC%20WMS%201.1.0%20Implementation%20Specification&ei=MXpxTePzBIS3tgfO4NWNDw&usg=AFQjCNEUPdTm9-g2O9-tUbpGMeoWIImpRA&sig2=52MoMH4SfHjU7KGmnRHtBw&cad=rja

Comment: I think that link was not the right one, the document name is: Web_Feature_Service_WFS_02-058.pdf, the correct link is : http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CD4QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.opengeospatial.org%2Ffiles%2F%3Fartifact_id%3D7176&rct=j&q=OGC%20WMS%201.1.0%20Implementation%20Specification%20document&ei=Rn1xTeSwE4-4tweq_MWBDw&usg=AFQjCNEEh8elsm23zFXijqCu7QMlBj4xYA&sig2=RoKZRh7CSo4UH2u84D7bGQ&cad=rja

Answer (score 5):

I've just tried the following:

http://ian01.geog.psu.edu:80/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:states&outputFormat=GML2&PROPERTYNAME=(STATE_FIPS,STATE_ABBR)

and it seems fine. Can you post a specific URL that doesn't work?